# How to deal with App Engine Devserver exception due to FormatStyle restricted class?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc

Developing a Google App Engine app with Spring MVC, the following exception presents itself while running the dev server on OSX:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0':
Initialization of bean failed [...]    


nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
java.time.format.FormatStyle is a restricted class. Please see the
Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

This error does not present itself if I upload my app to Google App Engine's cloud server.

How to get around it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeanCreationException throwed when trying to run my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543131/beancreationexception-throwed-when-trying-to-run-my-project)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrading Java 1.8 to 1.7 fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi Matoe,
I am running into the same problem.
Did you manage to find another solution in the meantime?
Best Regards

Comment: see my comment below. Using <runtime>java8</runtime> in appengine-web.xml will fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is not the answer most people would look for. Following is the solution to fix the problem.

use 

   `<runtime>java8</runtime>`

in

   `appengine-web.xml`

This will fix the problem. This doesn't require you to downgrade you java version from 1.8 to 1.7.