# HTTP ERROR 503 with Spring Framework

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

I am using appEngine with Spring Framework and maven. I run the application from maven and everything is fine in command line but in browser I found  this error. 
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

I don't know where I have to fix. Below is the error code in terminal when I try to run with maven. I think Spring framework has big problem in my PC.

```
    [INFO] WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.ConversionServiceExposingInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.time.format.FormatStyle is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.:
[INFO] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.time.format.FormatStyle is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

Comment: Please add some more information. Perhaps a log from server will help to understand the problem

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I update my question about error message. Please have a look!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeanCreationException throwed when trying to run my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543131/beancreationexception-throwed-when-trying-to-run-my-project)

Comment: Thanks.. I fixed that error yesterday. Like he said, I downgrade to java version 7. It work.